# How to add an 'on-click' background change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I am basically using this - http://jsfiddle.net/navjottomer/8u57u/4/ and also using Bootstrap's panel styles.

I want it to look more like this though - https://support.google.com/mail#topic=

I have no idea where to start in terms of changing the colour of the panel-heading on open / active / expanded. You can see in the example that it starts white, and changes to dark grey on expand.

Any info would be great!

Here's my current mock up:

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Overview</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                content here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Utilities</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle text-normalize" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="fa fa-plus text-primary"></i> Organization</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full code.

```js
var selectIds = $('#panel1,#panel2,#panel3');
  $(function($) {
  selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).prev().find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  });
  $(".panel-heading").find("a[data-toggle=collapse]").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
  $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
  $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass('open');
  } else {
  $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
  }
  });
  });
```

```css
.panel-default.open {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
  }
  .custom-panel .panel-default.open >.panel-heading {
  background: transparent;
  }
       .custom-panel .panel-default>.panel-heading {
         background: #fff;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
       </head>
 <body>
  <div class="panel-group custom-panel" id="accordion">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 1</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 1</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 2</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 2</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 3</a>
     </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!

Any ideas now how to over-ride the bootstrap defaults?
So with the bootstrap defaults, the panel-heading is a light grey color, but i would like the panel-heading to be WHITE on CLOSE.
and the RED on OPEN. 

Thanks!

Comment: Please wait, I will fix for you.

Comment: If any issues, you can ping to me. :)
My skype name. nhanhuynh.asnet

Comment: Nice to meet you. @becca

Comment: Tom,  I am having a small problem with the code - maybe you can help.

I have another accordion that starts open, so rather than

````              <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                        <div class="panel-body panel-body-help">
                           content
                        </div>
                    </div>````
the main line now has 'in' added to the classes. When I add this class, the on-open style does not apply ( i assume since it was not clicked open). How can i make this script work for on click and on open?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your css or pages header to forces the changes:

**Panel Heading:**

```
.panel-heading{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
 //more custom styles
}
```

**Panel Body on Expand:**

```
.panel-body{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  //more custom styles
}
```

Include this css AFTER loading accordion default css file, or use `!important` to force new properties.

*Edit color and background color values.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't change the panel-heading on active, that changes the panel heading all together. I need it to change just when that heading is active.

Im thinking i need a JS?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this script after the script you are using:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.panel-heading').removeClass('color');
    $(this).parents().eq(1).addClass('color');
});
```

And declare a CSS class with the background-color to the value you want

**CSS**

```
.color{
  background-color: red !important;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

**NOTE:** The !important may not be required if you declare this class after Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Not sure if i just dont get what you're meaning, or if it's not working.
I added the script and created the CSS class of "accordion-bk-change".
I added the color and transition, and it just stays that colour all the time instead of changing on click,

Comment: `.accordion-bk-change{
    .panel-heading{
       background-color:#616161!important;
       transition:all 1s;
    }
}
`

Comment: @becca Not sure if I understand, you mean it does change the first time, but when you click on a different panel heading it doesn't roll back?

Comment: Sorry - What i mean is that I have added the script and style, and it just changed the panel-heading to the colour always. It does not start off white and transition into grey. It is just grey always, even without clicking on it. It's halfway there, but I need the panel-heading to start off white, and transition into grey on click.

Comment: Have you checked if there are other CSS classes already declared that target your panel-heading? How is the HTML rendered? Because the script only adds the class on the click event in the anchor, otherwise that CSS class isn't added.

Comment: There are no other CSS classes except for bootstrap, which is compiled first. Can't figure out what I've done wrong. Sorry-  been coding for ~7 months so still learning.

Comment: Please verify this JSFiddle is an edit of the one you linked, how is this different from your code? http://jsfiddle.net/8u57u/216/ so I can edit my answer

Comment: That's exactly what I am using.
With bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 0):

Please try my example! I custom your code.

```js
var selectIds = $('#panel1,#panel2,#panel3');
$(function($) {
  selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).prev().find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  });
  $(".panel-heading").find("a[data-toggle=collapse]").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
      $(this).closest('.panel-group').find('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
      $(this).closest('.panel-default').addClass('open');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.panel-default').removeClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel-default.open {
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.panel-default.open .panel-heading {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 1</a>
            </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 2</a>
            </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 3</a>
            </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Contents panel 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi man, you need  add class collapsed into <a>: 
 <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Panel 3</a>
            </h4>